# Can I change a column title in a PostgreSQL Function?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a Postgres VIEW that uses a plpgsql function four times to produce an Aged Debt Report. If the row has a date in the current period the value in that row goes in col 1, if the date is last month then the value is in col 2 ... and so forth.
I call the function with a parameter and that parameter tells the function to calculate this month debt, last month debt, debt 2 months back - or in the final column everything before then.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agedebt4(beforem integer, d_details)
    RETURNS double precision AS
     $BODY$
    /* This Func creates a column for Aged Debt Reporting from d_details table
       The beforem parameter can be entered as 0,1,2 or 3
       0 shows current period debt, 1 previous period, 2 cur period -2
       and 3 shows current period less three AND EARLIER. */
    DECLARE
      curdt date =(CURRENT_DATE);
      curdy text = substring(curdt,1,4);
      curdm text = substring(curdt,6,2);
      curdmi int = curdm::int;
      curdyi int = curdy::int;
     -- blah
     -- blah
     -- blah
```

The VIEW has

```
SELECT agedebt4(0,d_details) AS "Current Debt", agedebt4(1,d_details) 
AS "CurrPeriod -1 Debt", agedebt4(2,d_details) AS "CurrPeriod -2 Debt", -- etc
```

But I wish to have the column titles changed inside the Function. So I could actually have `Oct2013 Debt`   `Sep2013 Debt`   `Aug2013 Debt` `July2013+` `Earlier` ... (obviously month names depending on the month of execution)  ... show on the output. I don't want to change the Function name from agedebt4 - that's fine. I want the Function to amend the displayed column title.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure, so you cannot to change a view (column label) from inner function. A main reason is a timing. Label is specified and hard coded before any execution. So you cannot to change it later - when function is executed. Same behave is with datatypes - it is fixed before any execution.